# When I link a blend file, why is the object showing up at 1/10th the scale?

Tags: modeling, objects

I have two blend files. Both files use distance in meters. The first file is a character of 2.267 meters tall. The second file is a single handed axe of height 56 centimeters. When I link the axe object to the character file the axe shows up, but is only 5.6 centimeters in height.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Axe blend file: http://cybermagesllc.com/models/Axe.blend

Comment: Try applying the scale (Ctrl-A) of the model you're importing before you import it.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion of applying the scale to the axe prior to linking it. This, unfortunately, does not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons this can happen are:

1. The file you are appending into has different units from the file you are appending from. You can go to the *Units* panel in the *Scene* tab to verify this.
2. You are using either *Metric* or *Imperial* units and the *Scale* value is different in both files.

Comment: The answer in this case was option #1. The Axe blender file specified a scale of 1.0 and the Character blend file specified a scale of 0.1.